# Какие знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Точного ответа на вопрос (?) сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два месяца на грудном вскармливании (?) не существует

Answer (score 2):

> Точного ответа на вопрос (?) сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два
>   месяца на грудном вскармливании (?) не существует.

Я бы выбрал такой вариант:

***Точного ответа на вопрос, сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два месяца на грудном вскармливании, не существует.***

Comment: Возможны и другие варианты, но этот - самый нейтральный, и потому в отсутствии контекста я бы выбрал его.

Answer (score 1):

1) Точного ответа на вопрос "Сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два месяца на грудном вскармливании?" не существует.

Здесь **прямая речь в роли несогласованного определения**.

2) Выбор **прописной букв**ы связан с распространенностью прямой речи, но можно использовать и строчную букву:

Точного ответа на вопрос "сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два месяца на грудном вскармливании?" не существует.

3) Вариант с классическим оформлением прямой речи также возможен:

Точного ответа на вопрос: "Сколько должен съедать ребёнок в два месяца на грудном вскармливании?" - не существует.

В этом случае **прямая речь внутри слова автора**.